# How do I get to use Model1.foo instead of Model1.edmx, and invoke IModelConversionExtension callbacks

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have a VSIX and a associated MEF DLL using IModelConversionExtension Class as per the documentation, and a pkgdef file setting up .foo as an extension to invoke the EF Designer.

```
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]
[Export(typeof(IModelConversionExtension))]
[ModelFileExtension(".foo")]
public class MyConversionCallback : IModelConversionExtension
{
    public void OnAfterFileLoaded(ModelConversionExtensionContext context)
    {
        //How does this get called?
        return;
    }

    public void OnBeforeFileSaved(ModelConversionExtensionContext context)
    {
        //How does this get called?
        return;
    }
}

[$RootKey$\Editors\{c99aea30-8e36-4515-b76f-496f5a48a6aa}\Extensions]
"foo"=dword:00000032
[$RootKey$\Projects]
[$RootKey$\Projects\{F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F}]
[$RootKey$\Projects\{F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F}\RelatedFiles]
[$RootKey$\Projects\{F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F}\RelatedFiles\.foo]
".diagram"=dword:00000002
[$RootKey$\Projects]
[$RootKey$\Projects\{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}]
[$RootKey$\Projects\{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}\RelatedFiles]
[$RootKey$\Projects\{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}\RelatedFiles\.foo]
".diagram"=dword:00000002
```

I can get both the similar Transform and Generation MEF Classes to work fine.
And my Model1.foo does invoke the EF Designer, but
 1. OnAfterFileLoaded and OnBeforeFileSaved never fire, and
 2. I get an error message when I try to save Model1.foo, which says to see errors in the Error List but there are none.

What am not doing to get this to work.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`OnAfterFileLoaded` is supposed to be invoked if you load a file whose extension is different than `edmx` and  the `IEntityDesignerConversionData.FileExtension` returns a value that matches your extension. `OnBeforeFileSaved` works the opposite way - on save. However - I looked at code in this area today and concluded that it actually cannot work. I filed a work item for this: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1371